# Comodo обнаружил сеть

Tags: сеть, firewall

Gomodo firewall написал "обнаружена проводная сеть 169.254.81.95/16" с вариантами "я нахожусь дома", "я нахожусь на работе", "я нахожусь в общественном месте". Варианта "блокировать подключение" или "игнорировать" почему-то нет. IP адрес мне совершенно не знаком. Что делать в этой ситуации? Является ли она попыткой вторжения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это адрес назначен службой [APIPA](http://wiki.compowiki.info/ChtoTakoeAPIPA).

У вас грамотный [firewall](http://developer-life.com/5529)

Comment: Спасибо. Я правильно понял, что ситуация штатная и не должна вызывать беспокойства?

Comment: Подобные адреса возникают, если у вас на компьютерах в локальной сети включена автоматическая раздача адресов по DHCP (это обычно по умолчанию), а самого раздатчика в сети не обнаруживается. Особенного повода для беспокойства тут нет, но всё же советовал бы проверить конфигурацию локальной сети! Очень похоже, что у вас временно отвалился роутер, который раздавал адреса компьютерам в локалке, а Комод новые, но стандартные для таких случаев адреса принял за новую сеть.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо, так и было